# How to view shapefile in web site?

Tags: shapefile, web-service

I have shapefile for my country and I want to view this map in my web site (browser) in my LAN network how to do that, is it possible?

Comment: You just want to view the shapefile online? Or do you want to add the shapefile in your map that you are running on localhost?

Comment: @HasanMustafa i want to view the shapefile in my website map that running in localhost

Comment: I would suggest that you expand your question with details on exactly what you want to achieve and what your limitations are. On the Answer you have mentioned that you don't want to use qgis2web, so it will be helpful to figure out what exactly you need. Please see this post for more details: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question

Comment: @user3368456 you say you have "a website map running in localhost" please give more input on what is this "map"...

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible but this will only work with a webmapping framework.
You can easily create such a webmap using [qgis](http://qgis.org/en/site/) and the [qgis2web](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2web/) plugin. The output is a folder which can be hosted anywhere.

There might be possibilities with ArcGIS but this might be answered by someone else.

You may want to check some online providers as well like cartodb or mapbox. But this will lead to a non local webmap which can be embedded.

Comment: Maybe try converting the shapefile to `GeoJSON` and displaying that on the map.

Comment: qgis2web will convert a shapefile to geojson by default!

Comment: I meant if didn't want to use qgis2web for some reason